# jQuery UI date picker won't appear if the window doesn't have focus

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, capybara, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an integration test, written in Ruby, using Capybara (Webdriver/Selenium) that finds the icon for a date picker and then clicks it, to open up the calendar for picking up the date:

```
find("input[type=date]").click
```

When the window in which the test is running, that is, the Firefox window, doesn't have focus, then the calendar doesn't appear (and the test fails).

Any ideas what's going on? or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong event. The datepicker is activated by a *focus*, not by a *click*. This example works fine in Firefox and Chrome when the window doesn't have focus:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#datepicker').focus();
}, 5000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dXJKL/

So try fixing your test to use `find('input[type=date]').focus()`.